# Getting Job Launcher ClassName is not set error on E-Mapreduce

Tags: apache-spark, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to run Spark and SparkSQL job from Alibaba E-MapReduce workflow console.

I am trying to run following command:

```
--master yarn-client --driver-memory 7g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 5g --executor-cores 1 --jars ossref://emr/checklist/jars/emr-core-0.1.0.jar ossref://emr/checklist/python/wordcount.py oss://emr/checklist/data/kddb 5 32
```

Getting the following error:

> Tue Jun 18 10:48:58 CST 2019 [LocalJobLauncherAM] INFO Starting emr
>   flow launcher am ...
>   =================PRINT RUNTIME ENV BEGIN=================
>
> == System Properties ============
>
> java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
>   sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64
>   java.vm.version=25.151-b12   java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/   path.separator=:
>   java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM   file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
>   user.country=US   sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
>   sun.os.patch.level=unknown   java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual
>   Machine Specification
>   user.dir=/mnt/disk1/flow-agent/local-rm/LocalApplication_1560824463304_2/container_1560824463304_2_01_000001
>   java.runtime.version=1.8.0_151-b12
>   java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
>   java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed
>   os.arch=amd64   java.io.tmpdir=tmp   line.separator=
>
> java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation   os.name=Linux
>   sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8   emr.flow.user=hadoop
>   java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/lib64:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native/::/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
>   java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
>   java.class.version=52.0   sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit
>   Tiered Compilers   os.version=3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
>   user.home=/home/hadoop   user.timezone=Asia/Shanghai
>   java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob   file.encoding=UTF-8
>   java.specification.version=1.8   flow.job.id=FJI-F6D6115A3E436AAC_0
>   java.class.path=launcher.jar   user.name=hadoop
>   flow.job.result.local.dir=/mnt/disk1/flow-agent/job-results
>   flow.job.launcher.class.name=com.aliyun.emr.flow.agent.jobs.launcher.impl.SparkSqlJobLauncherImpl
>   java.vm.specification.version=1.8
>   sun.java.command=com.aliyun.emr.flow.agent.jobs.launcher.local.LocalJobLauncherAM
>   java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre
>   sun.arch.data.model=64   user.language=en
>   java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>   awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit   java.vm.info=mixed mode
>   java.version=1.8.0_151
>   java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
>   sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/classes
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation   file.separator=/
>   java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
>   flow.job.meta.data.path=job.metadata
>   sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle   sun.cpu.endian=little
>   sun.cpu.isalist=
>
> == System Env ===================
>
> PATH=/usr/lib/spark-current/bin:/usr/lib/analytics-zoo/bin:/usr/lib/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/flow-agent-current/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/sbin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/sbin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/bin:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/sbin:/home/hadoop/.local/bin:/home/hadoop/bin
>   HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/ecm/hadoop-conf   HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
>   FLOW_AGENT_HOME=/usr/lib/flow-agent-current
>   JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native:
>   HISTSIZE=1000   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0
>   ZOOCFGDIR=/etc/ecm/zookeeper-conf   TERM=unknown
>   XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
>   HADOOP_PID_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-current/pids   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   XDG_SESSION_ID=c76
>   HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/apps/extra-jars/*:/usr/lib/spark-current/yarn/spark-2.3.2-yarn-shuffle.jar:/opt/apps/extra-jars/*
>   MAIL=/var/spool/mail/hadoop   SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark-current
>   ANALYTICS_ZOO_HOME=/usr/lib/analytics-zoo
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/lib64:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native/::/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native
>   YARN_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hadoop-yarn   JVMFLAGS= -verbose:gc
>   -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=128M -Xloggc:/mnt/disk1/log/zookeeper/zookeeper-gc.log -javaagent:/var/lib/ecm-agent/data/jmxetric-1.0.8.jar=host=localhost,port=8649,mode=unicast,wireformat31x=true,process=ZOOKEEPER_ZOOKEEPER,config=/var/lib/ecm-agent/data/jmxetric.xml
>   HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-current   LOGNAME=hadoop
>   PWD=/mnt/disk1/flow-agent/local-rm/LocalApplication_1560824463304_2/container_1560824463304_2_01_000001
>   _=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java   LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s   SHELL=/bin/bash   ANACONDA_HOME=/usr/lib/anaconda
>   OLDPWD=/mnt/disk1/flow-agent/local-rm/LocalApplication_1560824463304_2/container_1560824463304_2_01_000001
>   USER=hadoop   YARN_PID_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-current/pids
>   HADOOP_MAPRED_PID_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-current/pids
>   SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/ecm/spark-conf
>   HOSTNAME=emr-header-1.cluster-121550
>   SPARK_PID_DIR=/usr/lib/spark-current/pids
>   ZOO_LOG_DIR=/mnt/disk1/log/zookeeper
>   NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
>   HADOOP_MAPRED_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hadoop-mapred
>   HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop-current
>   HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hadoop-hdfs
>   FLOW_AGENT_CONF_DIR=/etc/ecm/flow-agent-conf   HOME=/home/hadoop
>   SHLVL=3   ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/usr/lib/zookeeper-current
>   SPARK_LOG_DIR=/mnt/disk1/log/spark
>
> == System Arguments =============
>
> []
>   =================PRINT RUNTIME ENV END================= Tue Jun 18 10:48:58 CST 2019 [LocalJobLauncherAM] ERROR Job Launcher ClassName is
>   not set, quit.

Comment: Are you trying to run the CreateJob API? I can see a list of params you're passing in but not the command name itself

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
--class <class_name> --master yarn-client --driver-memory 7g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 5g --executor-cores 1 --jars ossref://emr/checklist/jars/emr-core-0.1.0.jar ossref://emr/checklist/python/wordcount.py oss://emr/checklist/data/kddb 5 32
```

Looking at the error message you got, you should be just missing the class name parameter:

> ERROR Job Launcher ClassName is not set, quit.

I got the sample request for the E-MapReduce **[CreateJob](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/28149.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.13.17dd5a4cyd8dKg#concept-ims-lhb-kfb)** API as below:

```
https://emr.aliyuncs.com/?Action=CreateJob &Name=CreateJobApiTest-SPARK &Type=SPARK &EnvParam=--class%20org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi%20--master%20yarn-client%20%E2%80%93num-executors%202%20--executor-memory%202g%20--executor-cores%202%20/opt/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-examples*.jar%2010 &FailAct=STOP &amp;RegionId=cn-hangzhou &Common request parameters
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried with class name. but still no luck.

--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-client --driver-memory 7g --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 5g --executor-cores 1  ossref://emr/checklist/python/kmeans.py oss://emr/checklist/data/kddb 5 32